# reading the title of the screen window you are in

Tags: osx, macintosh

I'm drawing a blank. I know I can do

screen :Number1

for example to move a windows position, however I cannot read the title of said window. the only way I have found to do this is to  use control plus a, number twice, once to switch, once to read the title. is there a better way? I'm using mac os sierra btw, but I'm sure the same answer will apply to the ubuntu and Debian remotes I have set up.

Thanks.

Comment: you can list all the window titles in a menu with `control-a "`.

Comment: I'm not sure  if I read that right. I read control+a ". I'm using a screen reader here I got output such as Termcap entry written to "/var/folders/mt/b8xddyfx48s55gw9slh2r5m80000gn/T/.scre when I di that. I did not get the title of a window. The sasme thing happened when I did control+a period.

Comment: You can get the current title by using the command to change the name and then just pressing enter. `control-a A` then enter.

Answer (score 0):

@meuh is referring to screen's **`windowlist`** command, which should work for you by pressing the two characters <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>`"`</kbd> (control/A and double-quote).

Doing that shows the window numbers and window-titles in two columns, and you can press up/down cursor to move to select one.  It's the same information shown by <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> (the **`windows`** command, but arguably more accessible).

The screen bindings which I see (for OSX) use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>`.`</kbd> (control/A and dot) for the screen **`dumptermcap`** command.  But any of screen's bindings can be overridden in your `.screenrc` file.

Comment: Control a plus w works,  however I wanted to know how  I could read the title of the window I'm in with out doing control a, then number twice, for example control a, 1, control a, 1. The second press would say this is window 1, linux box" or what ever I called it. Is there another work around I can utilize here?

Comment: Apparently not (screen only shows how to navigate, doesn't do much for status information).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doing a control plus a, then number of window twice will have to serve as a workaround.